# Integration of a matrix exponential multiplied with a function.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

I am trying to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(\textbf{A}t) f(t)\,dt$, where **A** is $n \times n$ invertible matrix and $f(t)$ is a p.d.f..

Is there any other method to calculate it explicitly or numerically?

I used an Parlett-Schur algorithm but it seems to have instability...

Thanks.

Andrew.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you have to be careful that the integral converges.
If $A$ is diagonalizable with $A = S^{-1} \Lambda S$ and $\Lambda$ diagonal with diagonal entries $\lambda_j$ (the eigenvalues), then $\exp(At) = S^{-1} \exp(\Lambda t) S$ and 
your integral, if it converges, is $S^{-1} F S$ where $F$ is diagonal with
diagonal entries

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{\lambda_j t} f(t)\; dt = \mathscr M(\lambda_j)
$$

where $\mathscr M$ is the moment generating function for the probability distribution corresponding to this pdf (and thus the
Laplace transform of $f$ at $-\lambda_j$).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my insufficient explain. My **A** is a 200 by 200( 600 by 600, 800 by 800 ...) upper triangular matrix. The eigen-matrix **S** is ill-conditioned so matlab can not calculate its inverse. That is why I used Parlett-Schur algorithm. However, the result was bad. I got some negative values which is impossible.I hoped that the reason would be my mistake. However, the paper of Nicholas J. Higham mentioned that Parlett-Schur algorithm would be instable. So I am trying to merge Parlett-Schur with Krylov subspace and Lanczos algorithm method.